# add additional code to the existing function

Tags: javascript

My title can be misleading because I might have chosen poor words to describe it but there is my problem.

I have one constructor which has many methods. The object created with this constructor is passed around other methods of another and another constructors which can add more methods to the object.

My question is I want to execute one function call that has to be executed by all the methods whenever they are executed. How can I achieve this?

For example:

```
function foo(){
   this.method1=function(){}
   this.method2=function(){}
}

function run_this(){}
```

Now, I want to add to method1 and method2, basically run_this that should be executed by them after running the method but before returning which is, If now I call this.method1 for object created from foo, it should do the following:

```
 this.method()
 run_this()
```

**Note:** Please don't suggest adding the function to be executed inside the method call because like I said it is passed around various other objects which can assign other functions and I want every function assigned to execute that function call.

Comment: The downvotes without any reason is exactly the reason why I am gradually trying to shift away from SO.

Comment: i downvoted because your question is not clear, I made an attempt at answering it, but you kept telling me i was wrong.

Comment: Did I? Can you please read all my comments and point out where I said you were wrong. All I said was your answer was not able to provide me what I needed to accomplish. Is that wrong to say? Do you want me to accept answers that don't solve my problem? It would be different thing if I did not communicate to you. If you look closely  , you finally bailed out saying that there was no way. So, how does this make my question or my communication unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a proxy for an instance of foo that wrapps `method1` and `method2`.

```
function fooProxy(foo){
   this.method1=function(){ 
    var result = foo.method1();
    run_this();
    return result;
   }
   this.method2=function(){ 
    var result = foo.method2();
    run_this();
    return result;
   }
}

function run_this(){}

var proxy = new fooProxy(someFoo);
```

Comment: Daniel!!!! please!!! that was not I was expecting from you...Like I said in my question...it is passed around various objects that can add the method to the object so adding it to the method itself is not at all the option.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades its not clear what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, it is like this....the methods are already written...the damage is already done and I realize that I have to execute one piece of code after every method call associated with the object with absolute no chance of rewriting the particular piece of code at the bottom of all method call for every possible situation. What is my way out?

Comment: you could create a proxy object that wraps a foo.

Comment: Yes, but that does not fully accomplishes the task though...what about the methods added when passing around other objects? Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly same as what you answered but just I want to achieve the same effect without modifying the methods.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades then i'm sorry theres no other way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, though. I think I need to put more thoughts into this and if it does not work out, I might have to rewrite the whole thing again.